# Correct config to delete files after 7 days?

Tags: logrotate

Is this the correct config to delete files after 7 days using logrotate? It should rotate weekly. I'm pretty stumped on this one. Thanks.

```
/var/lib/rundeck/logs/rundeck/*/job/*/logs/*.blah.json {
  su root root
  weekly
  missingok
  maxage 7
  rotate 0
  nocreate
 }
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Is something not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config as presented suggests it would rotate once a week, and delete the rotated log(s) straight away, meaning you have no logs immediately after rotation.

If you want to keep the rotated logs for a week after rotation, use `rotate 1`. Immediately prior to rotation, you would have almost 2 weeks of logs.

If you only want to keep about a week's worth of logs, you'd need to use `rotate 7` and `daily`.

Comment: it is only keeping 3 days worth of logs with the above config.

Comment: As in the last 3 calendar days, or 3 days from the last week? Do the rotated logs contain more than one days worth of data? Is logrotate set up to run daily? Bearing in mind it has only been 3 days since you asked your question.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. It is keeping the last 3 calendar days and keeping one days worth of data. Logrotate is also set to run daily. Should maxage also be removed?

Comment: Worth a try, but what you report with the config as discussed doesn't really make sense so I'm not sure what's going on right now.